# Finding the function that satisfies $\lim_{t\to x} \frac{t^2f(x)-x^2f(t)}{f(t)-f(x)}=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, functions

I have been provided that a function satisfies this given condition:$$\lim_{t\to x} \frac{t^2f(x)-x^2f(t)}{f(t)-f(x)}=1$$
I need to find the value of $$L=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\ln(f(x)-\ln2)}{x-1}$$ where the limit has a non zero finite value.

My attempt
Since this is a $\frac00$ indeterminate form, I apply L'Hôpital's rule and obtain $$\lim_{t\to x}\frac{2tf(x)-x^2f^\prime(t)}{f'(t)}=1$$
I write this as $$\lim_{t\to x}\frac{2tf(x)}{f'(t)}-x^2=1$$
Putting $t=x$ $$\frac{2xf(x)}{f'(x)}-x^2=1$$
Putting f(x)=y and $f'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$, we obtain
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{1+x^2}$$
$$\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{2xdx}{1+x^2}$$
Integrating on both sides
$$\int\frac{dy}{y}=\int\frac{2xdx}{1+x^2}$$
$$\ln(y)=\ln(1+x^2)+c$$
$$y=e^{\ln(1+x^2)+c}$$
$$y=k(1+x^2)$$
Since $L$ is a non zero finite value, and the denominator tends to $0,$ the argument inside the logarithm should tend to $1$
$$\begin{align}f(1)-\ln2=1 &\implies 2k=1+\ln2\\&\implies f(x)=\frac{(1+\ln2)}{2}(1+x^2).\end{align}$$
Applying L'Hôpital's rule on $L$
$$L=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)-\ln2}$$
$$L=\frac{f'(1)}{f(1)-\ln2}$$
$$L=1+\ln2$$
However according to the answer key, the answer is $1.$
Can anyone tell me at what point I made a mistake in my solution, or if maybe the answer key is incorrect? Thank you.
PS: This is is my first question on this site so I'm sorry for any formatting issues in advance and would gladly fix them if you point them out to me.

Comment: Your work seems fine to me, I cannot find where $L = 1$ should come from. In fact, if you work backwards, you can deduce that $L = 1$ is impossible: the function $f$ depends on a single free parameter $k$, and it's uniquely determined once you impose the condition $\lim_{x \to 1} \ln(f(x)-\ln 2) = 0.$ So $L = 1 + \ln 2$ is the only possibility. Can you double check your answer key? Or maybe the limits in the hypothesis were a little different?

Comment: In your answer, you suppose that $f$ is differentiable. Is it really a hypothesis of the given problem?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Huh, no it is not a given, I guess i wrongfully assumed that. But as Anne displayed in the answers, the result is obtainable without the assumption.

Comment: @Edd As Anne showed the given answer would be obtained after a slight change in brackets in the question, I'm going to chalk the mistake up to a misprint.

Comment: My english is not fluent, what does your last sentence mean? Hopefully you won't modify your question, which would make my answer obsolete...

Comment: @AnneBauval I was talking about the modification you suggested in your answer when you said it could be a misprint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to assume that $f$ is differentiable, nor even continuous: it follows from the hypothesis $\lim_{t\to x} \frac{t^2f(x)-x^2f(t)}{f(t)-f(x)}=1,$ which is equivalent to
$$\lim_{t\to x}\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}f(x)$$
(see details below).

Your resolution of the corresponding differential equation then rightly shows that
$$f(x)=k(1+x^2).$$
The discrepancy between your solution and the answer key is certainly due to a misprint in the question. If you look instead for
$$L:=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(\ln f(x))-\ln2}{x-1}\in\Bbb R,$$
you will quickly find $k=1,$ and finally $L=1.$

Edit: details for the first step. The hypothesis rewrites
$$1=\lim_{t\to x}\frac{(t^2-x^2)f(x)-x^2(f(t)-f(x))}{f(t)-f(x)},$$
i.e.
$$1+x^2=\lim_{t\to x}\frac{(t^2-x^2)f(x)}{f(t)-f(x)},$$
which entails $f(x)\ne0$ and
$$\lim_{t\to x}\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}=\lim_{t\to x}\frac{t+x}{1+x^2}f(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}f(x).$$

Comment: Can you provide the offered details on that first step?

Comment: Actually just trying for the fraction to be constant, $\frac{t^2f(x)-x^2f(t)}{f(t)-f(x)}=1$, gives $\frac{f(t)}{1+t^2}=\frac{f(x)}{1+x^2}$. If $x,t$ are independent, then this fraction has to be constant, $f(x)=k(1+x^2)$, and this indeed is a solution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann indeed, but what is the point of such a stronger assumption?

Comment: Just that a fast guess is sometimes sufficient, and that the structure of the solution is directly encoded in the original equation. One would have to discuss uniqueness, and that is indeed easiest with the differential equation.